# get filename from modified url in php

Tags: php

**.htaccess**

> RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ get/get-post.php?link=$1&h_link=$2

what shows in url is

> http://example.com/post-name/sub-name

now i want to get the the name of file (using PHP) which you can see is `get-post.php`

i have tried using the `basename()` function but all it gives me is the sub-name part from the url.

Comment: have you tried `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`, `__FILE__`?

Comment: @Musa i did but no luck

Comment: @Musa Actually i worked, i wasn't looking at it the right way before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
$path = "/testweb/home.php";

//Show filename with file extension
echo basename($path) ."<br/>";

//Show filename without file extension
echo basename($path,".php");
?>
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_filesystem_basename.asp